# Await in static method

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method that I use to get string from web service

I started the code with

```
    var task = _tempClient.GetteststringAsync();
    string teststring = await task;
```

but I noticed that the code not wait till the call end and the value retrieved ,so I tried something like

```
    string teststring= string.Empty;
    var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Func<Task>(async () => teststring= await _tempClient.GetteststringAsync()))
.Unwrap();
    t1.Wait();
```

but this cause the application stuck , any idea how to make it work ,tempClient is a service refrence object . I use it to intialise the webrefrence in MVC Application, it's the helper class

Comment: Well the async method *will* wait until the `await` expression has completed. You haven't really given nearly enough information about what you're seeing, what kind of application you're writing etc for us to help you.

Comment: Code must not wait until task competes, it awaits to continue after completion.

Comment: my code depend my work on the retrieved value how to know that it was retrieved @HamletHakobyan

Comment: You don't have to care about it just put your continuation code after `await`.

Comment: I need this value to add security token to the class, which my code will check @HamletHakobyan

Comment: You say "I noticed that the code not wait till the call end and the value retrieved". What does that mean? your code is expected to be available to process more work, since one you `await` on something, control is yielded back to the calling method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx using this code looks like

```
AsyncPump.Run(async delegate

{

    await DemoAsync();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt was much closer to doing the right thing, calling `task.Wait()` or `task.Result` is a blocking call and can often cause a deadlock. Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for `async/await` best practices.

What you want to do is what you had first:

```
var task = _tempClient.GetteststringAsync();
string teststring = await task;
```

Calling `_tempClient.GetteststringAsync()` will start executing on a thread pool thread and once finished the result will be returned into `teststring` and the rest of the method will execute on the original request thread. At that point you just need to do whatever you need to with `teststring`.

Comment: `and the rest of the method will execute on the original request thread.` That's not fact. Depends on `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Agree, but he mentioned doing in this in MVC and also his program deadlocks, so I think if he called it from an MVC request thread it should continue execution on that thread